# Solve the equation $\left|\frac{x}{x-1}\right| = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question:**

Solve the equations

$$\left|\frac{x}{x-1}\right| = 1$$

**Attempted solution:**

$$\left|\frac{x}{x-1}\right| = 1 \Leftrightarrow$$

Distributing the absolute value function.

$$\frac{|x|}{|x-1|} = 1 \Leftrightarrow$$

Moving up the denominator:

$$|x| = |x-1| \Leftrightarrow$$

Critical events may occur at x = 0 and x = 1, so we have three different cases:

Case 1: $~~~~x \leq 0$

$$-x = x - 1 \Leftrightarrow 2x - 1 = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{1}{2}$$

However, this is a false solution, since $\frac{1}{2}$ is not less than 0.

Case 2: $~~~~0 < x < 1$

$$x = -(x-1)$$

This leads to 1 = 0 and thus no solution exists here.

Case 3: $~~~~x > 1$

$$x = x -1$$

This leads to a -1 = 0 expression and thus no solutions exists here.

This line of argument would lead one to conclude that there are no solutions for this, yet a sanity check with $x = \frac{1}{2}$ satisfies the relationship. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Cases 1 and 2 are incorrect. Check your algebra and signs carefully!

Comment: It might make your life easier to solve $\dfrac{x}{x - 1} = 1$ and $\dfrac{x}{x - 1} = -1$ instead of moving them around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the definition of $|f(x)|=c$. This means that $f(x)=\pm c$.

So case 1:

$$\frac{x}{x-1}=1$$
$$x=x-1$$

No solution.

Case 2:

$$\frac{x}{x-1}=-1$$
$$x=1-x$$
$$x=\frac12$$

Answer (score 5):

The equation $\lvert x\rvert=\lvert x-1\rvert$ can be interpreted as follow : What $x$ is at equal distance from both $0$ and $1$ ? Hence $x = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: nice(+1). no computations at all.

Comment: Indeed, +1. Easily best answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right setup but you made a couple of slight errors. In the first case, note that if $x\le 0$, then $x-1 < 0$ so $|x-1| = 1-x$. But there isn't a solution in this case anyway. In the second case, if $x = -(x-1)$, then $x = -x+1$.

Comment: +1 since the OP actually asked what was wrong with his reasoning. All the other answers just gave a solution, not what was asked.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do cases:
$$
|x|=|x-1|\implies 0=x^2-(x-1)^2=[x-(x-1)][x+(x-1)]=2x-1\implies x=\frac{1}{2}\cdot
$$
You then can verify that $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is indeed a solution.